# R- Error "survfit" formula, survival package

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm learning basics about survival package in R with [this tutorial](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/rsurv.pdf)

I followed the steps and got an error:
The data is in the package:

```
aml<-aml
```

And in page 2 of the tutorial:

```
summary(survfit(Surv(aml$time[1:11],aml$status[1:11])))
Error in UseMethod("survfit", formula) : 
  no applicable method for 'survfit' applied to an object of class "Surv"
```

So, I tried:

```
train<-Surv(aml$time[1:11],aml$status[1:11])
survfit(Surv(time, status), data = train)
```

And I got another error:

```
Error in Surv(time, status) : Time variable is not numeric
```

Really I don't know what I'm doing and why the steps from the tutorial are wrong.

Comment: You just reading an old tutorial. This formulation isn't allowed anymore. You also need to specify the RHS now, try `survfit(Surv(aml$time[1:11],aml$status[1:11]) ~ 1)` instead. You can also plot it using `plot(survfit(Surv(aml$time[1:11],aml$status[1:11]) ~ 1))`

Comment: thanks, would you recommend a new tutorial?

Comment: I'd recommend [Fox's Appendix](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-cox-regression.pdf), though it's pretty focused on Cox models.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your time variable to numeric type using following:

```
train$time = as.numeric(train$time)
```